# Как можно создать многоколоночный список циклом for на C#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
+[$$$]
+1,[$$$]
+1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Например тут **15** колонок (количество колонок указывается за ранее, может быть и 10 а может и 1000 колонок быть не суть) ,нужно чтобы на каждой колонке (то есть во всех единицах) побывала эта часть: **[$$$]** и нужно именно циклом for, какие есть варианты? помогите пожалуйста решить данную нестандартную задачу...

Вот правильный вариант если кому понадобится:

```
var columnCount = 15;
        string[] row = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            row = new string[i + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                row[j] = "1";
            row[row.Length - 1] = "[$$$]";
            Console.WriteLine($"+{string.Join(",", row)}");
        }
        for (int i = columnCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            row[i] = "1";
            row[i - 1] = "[$$$]";
            Console.WriteLine($"+{string.Join(",", row)}");
        }
```

спс всем вопрос решен...

Comment: Ваши варианты?.

Comment: Вот мой вариант: http://rextester.com/RHSG21723 пробовал не как, не чего на ум не приходит пока, если бы были варианты конкретные я бы не просил тут помощи новерно, честно такой задачей сталкиваюсь в первый раз...

Comment: Переоткрыть бы вопрос, чтобы можно было поместить ответ туда, куда следует — в ответы, а не сам вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: да но к сожалению закрыт, если откроют перенесу конечно...

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем как требуется, но сам доделаешь.

```
+[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$]
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+1,[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
+[$$$],1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var columnCount = 15;
            var rowCount = columnCount * 2 - 1;
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append("+");

                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
                {
                    if (rowIndex == columnIndex || rowIndex + columnIndex + 1 == rowCount)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append("[$$$]");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append("1");
                    }

                    if (columnIndex < columnCount - 1)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(",");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                stringBuilder.Clear();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: почти то что нужно но не совсем , вопрос все еще открыт, а без stringBuilder нет вариантов так понимаю? это не критично но все же может другие варианты есть еще?

Comment: И без stringBuilder возможно сделать. Алгоритм приведен, дерзай, меняй, пробуй!